# Unable to sign in with my Apple ID after updating my iPhone

Tags: apple-id, iphone

I got a notification to update the software on my iPhone 4S (A1387), so I updated it. After updating completed, it asked to sign in with your Apple ID.

I tried to sign in with my Apple ID, then it asked me to agree to some terms and conditions.

After I agreed to those, it is now showing notification **Could Not Sign In** several times. So having updated, I am now unable to sign in with my Apple ID.

Comment: Can you provide your old/new OS version and some screens ?

Comment: If you're using your data connection, go find a useable wifi - or vice versa.

Comment: I am using wifi only